# Async requests in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope, kotlin-android

I often get an error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, when I try get info from some api. I know that this problem is related to the main android thread, but I don't understand how to solve it - coroutines, async okhttp, or both?
P.S I have a bad eng, sorry.

My code:

MainAtivity.kt

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(), Alert {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var api: ApiWeather
    var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        api = ApiWeather(okHttpClient)

        binding.buttonGetWeather.setOnClickListener {
            val cityInput = binding.textInputCity.text.toString()
            if (cityInput.isEmpty()) {
                errorAlert(this, "...").show()
            } else {
                val city = "${cityInput.lowercase()}"
                val limit = "1"
                val appId = "key"
                val urlGeocoding = "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?" +
                        "q=$city&limit=$limit&appid=$appId"

                var status = false
                val coordinates: MutableMap<String, Double> = mutableMapOf()
                val job1: Job = lifecycleScope.launch {
                        val geo = api.getGeo(urlGeocoding)
                        if (geo != null) {
                            coordinates["lat"] = geo.lat
                            coordinates["lon"] = geo.lon
                            status = true
                        } else {
                            status = false
                        }
                }
                val job2: Job = lifecycleScope.launch {
                    job1.join()
                    when(status) {
                        false -> {
                            binding.textviewTempValue.text = ""
                            errorAlert(this@MainActivity, "...").show()
                        }
                        true -> {
                            val urlWeather = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?" +
                                    "lat=${coordinates["lat"]}&lon=${coordinates["lon"]}&units=metric&appid=${appId}"
                            val weather = api.getTemp(urlWeather)
                            binding.textviewTempValue.text = weather.main.temp.toString()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Api.kt

```
class ApiWeather(cl: OkHttpClient) {
    private val client: OkHttpClient

    init {
        client = cl
    }

    suspend fun getGeo(url: String): GeocodingModel? {
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()
        val responseStr = client.newCall(request).await().body?.string().toString()
        val json = Json {
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }
        return try {
            json.decodeFromString<List<GeocodingModel>>(responseStr)[0]
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return null
        }
    }

    suspend fun getTemp(url: String): DetailWeatherModel {
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()
        val responseStr = client.newCall(request).await().body?.string().toString()
        val json = Json {
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }
        return json.decodeFromString<DetailWeatherModel>(responseStr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `api.getGeo(urlGeocoding)` runs in the current thread. `lifecycleScope.launch {}` by default has `Dispatchers.Main` context, so calling api function will run on the Main Thread. To make it run in background thread you need to switch context by using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. It will look like the following:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
      val geo = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { api.getGeo(urlGeocoding) }
      if (geo != null) {
           coordinates["lat"] = geo.lat
           coordinates["lon"] = geo.lon
           status = true
      } else {
           status = false
      }

      when(status) { ... }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already using coroutines. The problem is that `lifecycleScope` is tied to main thread. You want to replace it with `GlobalScope` or `coroutineScope` (latter is better in terms of complex project, but I assume you are writing pet-project now, so `GlobalScope.launch` will be fine)

Comment: thanks! For future people: if you use this solution and you have toasts/dialogs, you should set "applicationContext" to context

Answer (score 1):

you should replace

```
lifecycleScope.launch{
```

with

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
```